# Can I use same model project for WPF and MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf

I want to develop 2 application one is WPF Window Application and ASP.Net MVC application.

So we do have a same data access layer and business layer for both application.

so can we use same model for both application.

Note that :
Worry is not DAL, but my model project.

Model project contains Entity.

My Entity contains features related to WPF like InotifyPropertychanged, observablecollection.

If i am using same entity for MVC, is it really overhead to it or not ?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The model will raise all these events that are not being listened to - there is a bit of overhead in maintaining the invocation lists and checking whether there are listeners. All of this is likely to be very small overheads - probably not worth worrying about.

The real issue is that of suitability - WPF and MVC are very different and the applications you are developing with each are certain to be different. That means that you will need to change the model to suite one or the other, but making it evolve to suite both may very well be tricky if not impossible in some scenarios.

You should have a different view model for WPF from the MVC one, as it is unlikely for one model to suite both.

Comment: I'm a little confused when you guys speak about Model - is that a misuse for ViewModel ? It's a little bit off topic but is the architecture : (Entity - Model - ViewModel - View) or (Entity - Model - View) ?

Comment: @franssu - either, both. Model as in how you model the domain of discourse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can isolate your domain model and use it in both situations. However you shouldn't put specific related technology stuff into your entities.

My suggestion would be a service-oriented App. Use WCF, REST or similar services to work with the model, and both (Desktop and Web) use those services to retrieve the data that they need for presentation. You will be encapsulating your domain model, so it won't know anything about your presentation technologies.

Then you can get the data from your services and build your own model objects depending on your presentation's layer technology.

Comment: so in this case, I have to maintain two saperate models. But again it will lead the redudancy as I want common framework for both WPF and MVC.

Comment: Why do you need two separate models? All you need in your client apps (WPF & WEB) is data. Your centralized Model will do all the calculation and will return just data. Then in your client apps you can transform this data in your technology specific objects (ViewModels or whatever). They will only contain data, not any specific business operations. These operations belong to the centralized model.

Comment: so lets say for example, if centralized model will return person, then I have to create a one object of type person at UI and build that object according to my requirement. If I understood correctly, then isnt it overhead ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. It might seem overhead.. But are just data objects, it's not a good practice to put specific technology (WPF with INotifyProperty) into your entities. Anyway, your person object will be Ok in your Web app, in WPF you will have to create a Model with the entity. I think this is a common issue when dealing with SOA and WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use your model project that contains Entity.
About the over head the choice would be implementation of repository patterns and use.
If you want to use the same model project see the article [WPF Application framework(WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com/) also.